# Yii2. $(document).ready troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

AppAsset:

```
    public $js = [
    'plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js',
    'plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js',
    'app.js',
];
```

So I'm wiriting in view file:

```
 $script = <<< JS
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        App.init();
      });
    JS;
 $this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
```

It's not working in Yii in view file, I mean nothing happens. In simple html it's like:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    App.init();
});
</script>
```

And it's working.

I can't understand why it does not work in Yii.

Comment: Your question is not clear  what do you mean for App.init ..have you error in your browser  console .. What do you expect  to do  from  the  function

Comment: What you mean `does not work`? Do you have js files in correct order? Do you have single jQuery library loaded? Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: It's not important what does this function. I'm sure, Javascript file is correct, because it's working in simple html file. It doesn't work in Yii Project.

Comment: all files are loaded correctly.

Comment: Can you please mention what error you are getting? how would we know what "why it does not work" mean?

Comment: It does not work means it's doing nothing. Nothing happens. No errors, no any action. I edited question. Please, look it once again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this->registerJs()` creates a document ready wrapper by default, you just need to add the script which you want to include on a specific view in the first param of the function

```
$script='App.init();'; 
$this->registerJs($script);
```

Comment: are you sure the relative js is loaded on the page ? is there any error in console ?

Answer (score 0):

Yii2, by default, loads the javascript after the jQuery.
In the AppAsset.php, after the $js[] array, add the following code:

```
public $jsOptions = [ 
    'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD
];
```

Now it should work properly.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it didn't help.